# How does notepad.exe determine character encoding?

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I have a .txt file saved in UTF-8 format without a BOM. It contains an 'é' character.

How does notepad.exe determine that it is UTF-8 encoded?

Other .txt files containing only < 0x80 characters are opened as "ANSI" encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Raymond Chen:

> **[Some files come up strange in Notepad](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093)**
>
> [...] When faced with a file that lacks a special prefix, Notepad is forced to guess which of those two encodings the file actually uses. The function that does this work is [IsTextUnicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-istextunicode), which studies a chunk of bytes and does some statistical analysis to come up with a guess.
>
> And as the documentation notes, “Absolute certainty is not guaranteed.” Short strings are most likely to be misdetected.

(Related [follow-up blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223).)

Comment: Thx for the Raymond Chen links @user1686. I have looked into this in the years past, but never come across his articles. I wonder if Excel uses the IsTextUnicode() function itself when opening a TXT file?